# jQuery problems with tinybox

Tags: jquery

I'm using tinybox http://www.scriptiny.com/2011/03/javascript-modal-windows/ for a pop-up window. 
It looks like this:

```
TINY.box.show({
  iframe: "someDocument.html", boxid: "frameless", width: 300, height: 200,
  fixed: false, maskid: "bluemask", maskopacity: 40, closejs: function () {}});
```

I'm using this with jQuery and it works fine when I launch it. But the problem is that I can't change anything when it's open, I want to add an event. I'm using a iframe as shown. Any ideas?